# “'NoneType' object is not iterable”: I know my function returns nothing, but

Tags: python

I am trying to learn about exception handling, and wanted to give myself some practice. Below is my code which gets the user to input a fraction, and prints it back on the screen. My problem is, the final return statement is returning none, so I get the error `NoneType' object is not iterable`. How can I handle this as an exception if the user were to not enter a fraction?

```
def printing_fractions():
    frac = str(input("Input a fraction then press enter: "))
    try:
        n, d = frac.split('/')
        int(n)/int(d)
        return n,d
    except ValueError:
        print("You did not enter a fraction")    
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("You cannot divide by zero")
    return 

numerator, denominator = printing_fractions()
print "Your fraction is: " + numerator + "/" + denominator
```

Comment: How do you want to "handle" it?  That is, what do you want to do in that case?

Comment: I want to print something like "You entered an integer, please enter a fraction" - or just some sort of error message.

Comment: You're already doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are returning two different types from your function. In the first case: `return n,d` and in the second: `return None`

Then, you assume when you run the function that you will get back two values: `numerator, denominator = get_fraction()`

That line is where you are having problems. If you are returning `None`, which you currently have setup as a valid return, this will break.

One possible way to fix your code:

```
def printing_fractions():
    ...    
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("You cannot divide by zero")
    return 0,0

numerator, denominator = get_fraction()
if denominator != 0: print "Your fraction is: " + numerator + "/" + denominator
```

Edit:

Just wanted to note, normally when I'm catching exceptions like this I just use a single except:

```
def printing_fractions():
    frac = str(input("Input a fraction then press enter: "))
    try:
        n, d = frac.split('/')
        int(n)/int(d)
        return n,d
    except:
        print("Please try entering your fraction properly")    
        printing_fractions()
```

This will cause the exception to recursively call the function again, until proper input is provided.

Comment: [Don't use bare `except`, ever](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except), it catches a lot more than you bargained for!

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz Indeed it does! I tried that before I posted on here and it was pulling me up for more situations than I had intended.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I guess I'll go with except Exception in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Since, you're already printing an error message, I assume you would like to prompt the user for input again in case of an error.

```
def printing_fractions():
    while True:
        frac = str(input("Input a fraction then press enter: "))
        try:
            n, d = frac.split('/')
            int(n)/int(d)
            return n,d
        except ValueError:
            print("You did not enter a fraction")    
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("You cannot divide by zero")
```

This way if you catch an exception, user will be prompted for input again. This ensures that your function returns a valid fraction always.